# Calling an existing DataSet into a winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

This is a bit of an odd one as I know how to fix the issue in the code, but it involved changing the "DO NOT CHANGE" code in the form.designer

I have a data set I want creating outside the form.

```
Jewels ds = new LoadDataTable().Load();
```

I then make the form using form designer. After setting all data up, the table is empty.

this is because in the form.designer the line

```
this.jewels = new JewelsOfExile.Jewels();
```

exists,

if i edit this code to 
    this.jewels = ds;

it fixes it and uses my existing dataset. Great!!

But this messes over with the designer and breaks the tool. If i make any changes to the tool it reverts my changes and makes new variables (jewels1)

How do i go about loading in my Dataset without manually changing the designer.

full code snippets below

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using JewelsOfExile.Tables;

namespace JewelsOfExile
{

static class Program
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Jewels ds = new LoadDataTable().Load();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(ds));
    }
}
}

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JewelsOfExile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(Jewels ds)
        {
            InitializeComponent(ds);
        }
    }
}
```

and the code I shouldnt edit

```
private void InitializeComponent(Jewels ds)
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.jewels = ds;
        this.affixesBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
etc.....
}
```

Helped resolved thanks to Archer,

Added an onload event in the form and removed the creation in main.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Jewels jewels = new LoadDataTable().Load();
        affixesBindingSource.DataSource = jewels;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just put `Jewels ds = new LoadDataTable().Load();` in `InitializeComponent()` (or inside the form load event, like it should be)?  Are you making this a ton more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: breaks the tool. all changes that i make disapear and it reverts to an empty form of default size in the viewer. the code itself works if i run the program but it means i can no longer use the form designer tool to make changes to the form


Jewels is the name of the Dataset. jewels is an instance of that dataset.

Comment: @Archer I cant put anything in the InitializeComponent() as that is a generated class from the designer.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the form constructor where that is called, but either way you should be using the load event of the form and just calling `this.jewel = new LoadDataTable().Load();`

Comment: would that be making a onLoad() class in the Form1 class?

Comment: No - the load event is an event of the form.  Do you not know how to add event handlers for objects in the designer?

Comment: Hi @archer although that appears fixes the issue, it is still making a new dataset. so it would not be communicating with the original ds.

Comment: No - the load event is an event of the form. Do you not know how to add event handlers for objects in the designer?

no i dont.

Comment: Okay - open the form in the designer (visual, not code) and click it so that the form itself is selected in the properties window.  At the top of that window is a button that looks like a lightning bolt - click that.  Then look down the list and find "Load".  Double-click the right column next to that and will create create an empty event handler for the load event and show you it in code.  Put *all* your code for loading the dataset in that function.  It will be executed when the form is loaded.  Then remove all other data loading code that you'd previously added.

Comment: @archer   I did, i went to the lightning bolt. set Form1_load as a onload event and in that function set jews = loaddata etc. still creates a blank table. do i need to do a refresh of the form/datatable?

Comment: No - if it's valid then it will show in whatever you're displaying it in.  There are far too many unknowns here for me to help effectively, but you're definitely better off removing all the previous code you had for loading the data (in Main and InitializeComponent) and get it working in the form load event handler.  There is no reason why it won't work there, so something else is causing the problem.  Once you've done all that, put a breakpoint on the line that loads the data, run the application and check that it's being loaded correctly.

Comment: So I can tell the Load event works internally, I can do

`private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)`
        `{`
            `Jewels jewels = new LoadDataTable().Load();`

            `var debug = jewels.Affixes.Rows[5]["Name"];`
            `var debug2 = jewels.Attributes.Rows[1]["Id"];`
        `}`

the debug vars return values. so the jewels object is getting set correctly. However the DataGridView in the form is still empty.

Comment: In that case the binding is the problem.  You should literally be able to just say `dataGridView1.DataSource = {a relevant data source}` and it works.

Comment: Hi Archer.

many thanks, I added the above but it didnt work, however if instead of the view i set the binding source

`Jewels jewels = new LoadDataTable().Load();`
`affixesBindingSource.DataSource = jewels;`

It is fixed. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: is there now anyway to make reference to the dataset from the main method now? obviously now I have moved the generation of the dataset from the main to the load event, main cant get a reference to it. (as initiaze Component is private so the generation of the dataset is in a private class)

Comment: Main should not have a reference to it - that's part of the whole point.  Why do you think it needs it?

Comment: so i have a dataset but I want to do stuff to it. Or should all of that be part of the form class rather than main.

Comment: Try to get into the habit of narrowing down what responsibilities pieces of code actually have.  For example, `Main()` starts your application, so let it start the application and nothing else.  If Form1 (or whatever it's called) needs to create another form that also needs the dataset then you can always add a constructor to the other form that takes the dataset as a parameter, like you originally had with the main form.  A lot of good programming is to do with things that may seem unimportant, but given time will become clear and very valuable.

Comment: In this case, if nothing else needs the dataset then the main form is the best place to create the instance of it.

Comment: Thank you,

Shall remember that. I am a hobbyist coder with no formal training so its always been trying to stick bits of knowledge together and often get 2+2 = 3.95, mostly their but not quite enough to get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Helped resolved thanks to Archer,

Added an onload event in the form and removed the creation in main to the load event.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Jewels jewels = new LoadDataTable().Load();
    affixesBindingSource.DataSource = jewels;
}
```